# Reactjs Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): context is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJs and am trying to use context to change the state of my home page when I press login. `setAuthState` is what I'm trying to use to change the state. However, it keeps giving me `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setAuthState is not a function`. I have imported useContext and useState and the AuthContext file that creates the context.

Login.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";

const { setAuthState } = useContext(AuthContext);

const login = () => {
    const data = { username: username, password: password };
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/auth/login", data).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.error) {
            alert(response.data.error);
        } else {
            alert("Login successful");
            localStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.data);
            setAuthState(true);
        }
    })
};
```

AuthContext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext({});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another function for dispatch. You can look at the below sandbox. This link will help you.

[Codebase](https://codesandbox.io/s/login-authentication-usecontext-66t9t?file=/src/Context/context.js)

If u need more explanation on it, check [this](https://soshace.com/react-user-login-authentication-using-usecontext-and-usereducer/)